# Axon: JUnit Test. How to change the creation time of given events by testFixture?

Tags: axon

i try to test the ordering of event and i need a possibility to change a creation event time of given events by the testFixture in JUunit test.

in the test method i have already tryed following, i set the given current time of testFixture **andGivenCurrentTime** to yesterday

```
final Instant minus = Instant.now().minus(1, ChronoUnit.DAYS);

testFixture.given(someInitializationEvent, someUpdateEvent).andGivenCurrentTime(minus)
        .when(reduceCommand)
        .expectEvents(new ReduceApprovedEvent(anyString, order.getQuantity()));
```

but i if i start this test, i got an event, on event sourcing handler method **on(...)**, with current timestamp instant yesterday. the timestamp of event was not changed

```
@EventSourcingHandler
protected void on(AvailableQuantityUpdatedEvent event, @Timestamp Instant timeStamp) {
  this.quantity = event.getQuantity();
  this.lastUpdateFromPartner = Date.from(timeStamp);
}
```

what do i'm wrong?
And how can i handle this?

thx.

Answer (score 1):

The `givenCurrentTime()` instruction for the fixture was originally meant for testing deadlines using the deadline manager. By changing the time, one could trigger deadlines to occur.

However, the APIs may cause confusion and make its user believe it's meant to set the clock for the events as well.

Also, in your fixture, you set the clock to a timestamp after publishing the events. Even if the `givenCurrentTime()` method were to change the event's clock, it would not affect any events already recorded.

Comment: Thx, but how can I change the event‘s clock before publishing the  events?

Comment: There is a fix to the API in AxonFramework 4.0.1 that should help. You can now set the time before registering events, and the time is now also used to set the timestamp for events.